# how to search like google in combobox C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, autocomplete

I have a combo box and I have a lot of items so I need to search in the combobox.

How can i search like Google in a combobox?

**Code**

```
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="533,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  Name="combobox1" SelectionChanged="combobox1_SelectionChanged"   Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.MahName, ElementName=combobox1}"  />
```

and ...

```
        combobox1.ItemsSource = database.Mahs.ToList();
        combobox1.DisplayMemberPath = "MahName";
```

What should I do?

Comment: I believe there is an option on the combo box for AutoComplete

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Suggest instead of using SuggestAppend

```
this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Comment: i get error on first AutoCompleteMode and AutoCompleteSource.      error = " Combobox does not contain a definition for 'AutoCompleteMode' and no extension method 'AutoCompeleteMode' accepting a first argument of type 'Combobox' could be found "